# NIR.subtract is not a function?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, error, java, ndvi

```
var image = S2.filterBounds(lago)
.filterDate('2022-07-20', '2022-07-22');  //[1 image]


var RED = image.select('B4');

var NIR = image.select('B8');

var NDVI = NIR.subtract(RED).divide(NIR.add(RED));
```

ERROR: NIR.subtract is not a function

Why???

I am using imagecollection

Answer (score 2):

If `image` is an `imageCollection` then you can't do maths like add and subtract on it. It looks like (from your comment) you only have one image in the collection, so you can for example take that one image using `.first()` and do maths on that. Here's a modified GEE example from the demo docs:

```
// Load Landsat 7 raw imagery and filter it to April-July 2000.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1')
    .filterDate('2000-04-01', '2000-04-02');

// image is an ImageCollection. 
    
var RED = image.select('B4').first();
var NIR = image.select('B8').first();
print(NIR) // these are images
print(RED)
var NDVI = NIR.subtract(RED).divide(NIR.add(RED));
```